# UTF-32 encoding output value

Tags: python, encoding

in python, I use `encode` with `utf-32` encoding, result like this

```
>>> a = u"A"
>>> a.encode("utf-32")
'\xff\xfe\x00\x00A\x00\x00\x00'
>>> len(a.encode("utf-32"))
8
```

length is 8

however, at this site http://macchiato.com/unicode/convert.html, use UTF-32BE, output

```
00 00 00 41
```

the length is 4

why not equals with two values.

Comment: Looks like Python included a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). `A` in UTF-32 is four (8-bit) bytes.

Answer (score 2):

As Biffen correctly pointed out in a comment, Python includes a BOM (a Byte-Order-Mark). For UTF-32, this is `ff fe 00 00`. The `A` itself is encoded as `41 00 00 00`. If you don't want a BOM, use `utf-32le` instead. And since you're comparing it with a UTF-32BE encoding, you can also use `utf-32be` in Python to get the Byte order reversed:

```
>>> "A".encode("utf-32")
b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00A\x00\x00\x00'
>>> "A".encode("utf-32le")
b'A\x00\x00\x00'
>>> "A".encode("utf-32be")
b'\x00\x00\x00A'
```